# Выделение текста

Tags: html, css

```
::selection  {
    color: #ea4525;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-shadow: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;      
}
```

Выделение текста не работает полностью, меняется только цвет текста. Пробовал `!important`, результата нету. Подскажите, как сделать рабочее выделение?

Comment: А точно можно что-то кроме цвета и background-color менять?

Comment: Мне нужно поменять все значение которые написаны. А Что можно или нельзя Я не знаю, поэтому и спрашиваю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте JS: `имя_обьекта.focus();` или `имя_обьекта.select();`